# C# startup form unable to be shown

Tags: c#, forms, startup

This is my first assignment using C# and I've learned briefly about programming with Python in my pre-u. The C# form that I would like to show the user upon logging in can't be shown and instead, the program displays the Built errors msg, where I click on 'Yes' to continue running the last successful build. However, it will show one of the previous forms (which I have deleted from the program) instead - making it hard for me to test run and check for any other errors in my program.

The form I would like to show is **TechnicianHome**.

Error

> There were built errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?

Any help is much appreciated.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ASSIGNMENT
{
    public partial class TechnicianHome : Form
    {
        public static string name;

        public TechnicianHome()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public TechnicianHome (string n)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            name = n;
        }

        private void TechnicianHome_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            lblWelcome.Text = "Welcome" + name; 
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ServiceRequests vr = new ServiceRequests();
            this.Hide();
            vr.ShowDialog();
        }

        private void button1_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateProfile up = new UpdateProfile();
            this.Hide();
            up.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add exact error the program shows when you run in the question.

Comment: I suggest you add `this.Show()` as the last line in both button click events. Otherwise, you have lost the `TechnicianHome` form.

Comment: The exact error message of the popup was: There were built errors. Would you like to continue and run the last successful build?

Comment: Other than the “*” character at the top and bottom of the using statements...  the code “looks” OK with the exception of my previous comment. Have you tried `Build->Clean Solution` ?

Comment: Ah the "*" is an accidental typo I made as i was editting my question just now. I just tried the Build -> Clean Solution but there seems to be no difference in the output

Comment: try:     vr.ShowDialog();  then this.Hide();

Comment: @JohnG
The exact error code for the last line: 

` private void TechnicianHome_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) `

was   _Type 'TechnicianHome' already defines a member called 'TechnicianHome_Load' with the same parameter typ_

Comment: I've deleted the duplicate 'TechnicianHome_Load' and changed a line in Program.cs from **Application.Run(new Login());** to **Application.Run(new TechnicianHome());**. But for some reason it still shows the old deleted form :__).

Comment: It still shows the old deleted form because you're still telling it to. "There were errors, do you want to run the last version instead?" means "your code has problems that prevent it from being compiled into a working exe. Do you want to give up and run the previous exe which did make successfully, even if that was hours or days ago and doesn't include any of the work you've done since that time?" And you keep saying yes, then going "huh, why doesn't it include any of the work I've done since then?"

Comment: The error message tells you that the compiler parser has found errors in your code and so, the compiler cannot "build" (IE make an exe) from the latest version of your code. This means also that in your Visual Studio's Error List Window there is the exact reason why the compiler cannot build your code. Look at that window and try to fix the error/s listed there

Comment: You need to fix every single problem with the code. They're  all listed in the errors window and they have a red wiggly line underneath them in the code view. If you can't see the errors window, perform a Reset Window Layout (Window menu) and then look at the bottom part of the visual studio window. See here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-and-fix-code-errors?view=vs-2019

Comment: I see, many thanks for pointing it out! c: @Steve

Comment: I see, much thanks for pointing that out :) @CaiusJard